# Is ES7 only composed of two features?

Tags: ecmascript-2016

According to this blog: https://webapplog.com/es7-es8/

ES7 features are:

1. Array.prototype.includes
2. Exponentiation Operator

Is this right? If it is, why it took a year to commit only two minor changes to the standard (`Array.prototype.includes` is *just an alias* to `indexOf !== -1`)?

Comment: What makes you think they took a year? What did you expect, to have more features? If so, which?

Comment: Simple: all the major changes to the standard took longer than a year.

Comment: Btw, `includes` works different than `indexOf` for `NaN`

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean that bigger changes just will be included in next versions?

Comment: They *were* included in the next version, which has already been released.

Comment: What version? When they were released?

Comment: Please use a search engine.

Comment: I've added the explanation to the answer. It looks like there is some confusion between 'ES7' name (which is deprecated) for everything after ES6, and 'ES7' name (which is just incorrect) for ES2016.

Comment: Also have a look at the [tag:ecmascript-7] tag description that someone carefully created ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Yes](http://2ality.com/2016/01/ecmascript-2016.html)**, those were the new features ready at the time.

Of course, there also have been [lots of editorial changes](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/commits/es2016) that fixed minor spec issues.

Notice that instead of ES7 (ECMAScript 7. Edition) one should rather use the term ES2016 to refer to that release with its [relatively low significance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2016). "ES7" was at the time (between the releases of ES2015 and ES2016) often misused as a synonym of [ES.next](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_Next_support_in_Mozilla), which includes the features that landed in later releases and the ones that never were parts of any specification.