# What is jshint referring to with ES8 and ES9?

Tags: javascript, jshint

Obviously these are two versions of JavaScript but a Google of ES9 does not pull up anything except this:

[medium - es 2018](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-whats-new-in-ecmascript-2018-es2018-17ede97f36d5) which gives practical uses of es 2018.

Is es - 2018 referring to ES8 or ES9?

Where can I find some info on practical uses of ES9?

jshint clearly shows that you can configure for ES8 or ES9 here - jshint - options - [esversion](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion)

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744386/1048572) for a bit of history.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 = ES2015

ES7 = ES2016

ES8 = ES2017

ES9 = ES2018

A new specification comes out each year (since then), so ES9 is ES2018, which includes `Promise.finally`, object rest/spread, regex named capture groups, regex lookbehind, regex `s` (dotall) flag, and a few other things.

> ECMAScript 2018 introduced support for asynchronous iteration via the AsyncIterator protocol and async generators. It also included four new regular expression features: the dotAll flag, named capture groups, Unicode property escapes, and look-behind assertions. Lastly it included rest parameter and spread operator support for object properties.

There are descriptions of ES2018 features all over:

https://www.google.com/search?q=es2018+features

Here's one link:

https://www.sitepoint.com/es2018-whats-new/

You can read the official specification for it here:

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/

Comment: ES* = something to blog about each year, ES35 = Plz no more sugar!

Comment: Interesting how the last digit is off by 1.  Seems like a good way to remember from ES6 to ES9, 2015 to 2018.  When is 2019 due?

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi It's already out. See https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/

Comment: Why is it not in your list as ES10?

Comment: @DaraKhosrowshahi I thought the pattern was clear already. There's also ES5, ES3, ES2, ES1